# Why am I failing to get all values from the mysql column?

Tags: php, mysql

I've puzzled out building a mysql database, learned the basics of php, html, and css....and I can't, for the life of me, see why this simple query does not return all the column values that are showing in the table.  It is a voting site, table named data_(date)...in this case data_12_14_15.  There are many columns, but for simplicity, I'll stick with option_key which has 3 values...1,2,3....and Counter....0,0,4.  All values were populated with NOT NULL at table creation and contain 0s so they can be incremented easily, and all columns are INT(9) except for option_key which is TINYINT.  All I'm really after is counter, but the query fails with either column...except it doesn't fail, it's just that the array never gets all the values.  Confession: I've laughed when someone says they spent '2 HOURS!' on a problem.  I've spent 2 days, repeatedly, in this process.  Your turn to laugh.
I've cut the code down to nothing and still can't get it to work.

```
<?php
    include 'AV2connect.inc.php';
    include 'AV2core.inc.php';

    $query = "SELECT option_key FROM data_12_14_15";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    var_dump($row);
/*
  array (size=1)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
*/
    ?>
```

I'm using WAMP, Chrome, and have had pretty good luck up to now.  Thanks.

Comment: You're gonna laugh. You need a loop to pull all of the values. Something like `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { var_dump($row); }`

Comment: where is `$mysqli` initialized? Edit: never mind, didn't realize you were just getting one row, I think Terminus is correct

Comment: Yes, I did figure out long ago that a loop would work, and I sorta get what's been said...BUT...over and over in the tutorials it tells you that you can just put in a column heading, say, 'Names' and it will return all the names.  Maybe I've got a mental block going here and am missing the diff between column and row.  Trying hard to do this in one call to the database...and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_fetch_array()` only fetches one row at a time. If you want to load the entire result set into an array you need to use

```
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
```

which requires that your PHP server have the `mysqlnd` driver installed.

You could also use either of the following:

```
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

The first gives you an array with columns indexed by column name; the second gives both named and numbered columns.

If you don't have `mysqlnd` installed (check the output of `phpinfo()` to find out) you'll have to call `mysqli_fetch_*` in a loop to read through the result set one record at a time.

Hope that helps.

Comment: YES!  That did work without having to change any settings.  Thank you very much.